# Prevent combination of multiple selectors

Tags: sass

I'm trying to group all my vendor-specific stuff into a placeholder selector like this:

```
%search-bar-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

.search-bar::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    @extend %search-bar-placeholder;
}

.search-bar:-moz-placeholder {
    @extend %search-bar-placeholder;
}

.search-bar::-moz-placeholder {
    @extend %search-bar-placeholder;
}

.search-bar:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    @extend %search-bar-placeholder;
}
```

And then it compiles to this:

```
.search-bar::-webkit-input-placeholder, .search-bar:-moz-placeholder, .search-bar::-moz-placeholder, .search-bar:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red; }
```

How can I make sure Sass doesn't put all the selectors together ? Like this:

```
.search-bar::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

.search-bar:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

.search-bar::-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

.search-bar:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to keep them separate? It's more optimal to comma separate them.

Comment: Because vendor-prefixes don't work if they are all on the same line.

Comment: Why not use autoprefixer and stop managing this at this level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking at [Extend/Inheritance](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7) at sass-lang.com it seems that the selectors will always be comma separated. Even if you add another property, it will keep the shared properties in the comma separated list, and add another selector just for that overridden value.

The way I achieved what you want is by using a mixin. Though it's not really the purpose of a mixin, it does get the job done. Your style is still centralized and you can print it out in each selector using a one liner too.

```
@mixin placeholder-properties() {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.search-bar::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   @include placeholder-properties();
}

.search-bar:-moz-placeholder {
  @include placeholder-properties();
}

.search-bar::-moz-placeholder {
  @include placeholder-properties();
}

.search-bar:-ms-input-placeholder {  
  @include placeholder-properties();
}
```

The result will the following.

```
.search-bar::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.search-bar:-moz-placeholder {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.search-bar::-moz-placeholder {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.search-bar:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/humokax/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do that:

Define a mixin named `placeholder-styling()`:

```
@mixin placeholder-styling() {
  // Create a list of vendor-specific selectors for placeholders
  $vendor-selectors: (
    '&::-webkit-input-placeholder',
    '&::-moz-placeholder',
    '&::-ms-placeholder',
    '&::placeholder'
  );

  // Loop through each vendor selector in the list
  @each $selector in $vendor-selectors {
    // For each vendor selector, apply the following styling
    #{$selector} {
      @content; // Inject the styling content provided when using the mixin
    }
  }
}
```

Use the `placeholder-styling()` mixin

```
.search-bar {
  @include placeholder-styling() {
    // Inside the mixin, set the styling for the placeholders
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
  };
}
```

The mixin allows you to define this styling once and have it applied to all vendor-specific placeholders, providing a cleaner and more efficient way to handle cross-browser styling.